# Sort Specific Range VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to sort a range based on a specific criteria when the user select check boxes from a user form in Excel.

The user is given the option of 4 check boxes (each check box will sort a specific range). I've tried a few methods and can't seem to figure it out, I keep getting "Object Required" on run-time error

```
Private Sub btnConfirm_Click()

    If (chkbxValid.value) Then
        SortData (Range("H4:I1000"))
    End If
    If (chkbxValidDuplicate.value) Then
        SortData (Range("K4:L1000"))
    End If
    If (chkbxInvalid.value) Then
        SortData (Range("N4:O1000"))
    End If
    If (chkbxInvalidDuplicate.value) Then
        SortData (Range("Q4:R1000"))
    End If

End Sub
```

And then here's the second segment of code

```
Private Function SortData(rng As Range)

    FR = 1
    FC = 1
    LR = 1000
    LC = 2
    SC = 2

    Sheets("TRACKER_2.0").rng(cells(FR, FC), cells(LR, LC)).Sort Key1:=Range(cells(FR, SC), cells(LR, SC)), Order1:=xlAscending

End Function
```

Comment: You're trying to use more than 1 column as the key.

Comment: Drop the brackets around your function calls. Also, `Key1` must specify the first sort field, you are using the whole range so that may have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorting, there are more criteria:

```
fr = 1 'first row
fc = 1 'first column
lr = 200 'last row
lc = 10 'last column
sc = 4 'sort column
Range(Cells(fr,fc),Cells(lr,lc)).Sort key1:=Range(Cells(fr,sc),CellS(lr,sc)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Using Range("A1") style format:

```
lr = 200 'last row
Range("A1:J" & lr).Sort key1:=Range("D1:D" & lr), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: You may want to specify the sheet object name before the range object, depending on how the button is interacting.

Comment: I edited my `SortData(rng As Range)` function and still getting an error there, I've also updated the comment to what I corrected it to... I'm now getting **Object doesn't support this property or method**

Comment: Also, can I ask what the sort column means? I understand the rest except for that

Comment: @Maldred Sort column is the single column you will sort by.  In the key1:= that sort column is used.  The overall range you are encompassing when sorting is before the .Sort (so rows 1 one to 200, from A to J, is sorted based on content of Column D (4)).  If you're getting an object error, we might need to change that key to using Range("A1:A" & lr) format, which makes that sc irrelevant... same for the overall Range.

Comment: I'm passing in a Range into this method, wont that cause an issue if it's trying to sort the range I want to pass in?

Comment: @Maldred If you want to define the range outside, you can replace Range("") with rng or whatever it is; you will need to have it listed somewhere.  In the intiial post, there was no range to work with, so I gave arbitrary values (hence fr, fc, etc.) to show all of what was missing.